Correct way to create a Games table with 2 player column?
There is a database with tables:

Users
Tournaments
Participants
Games
Avatar

Where, Users is the user model, avatar holds addresses to png files to set avatar for user.
Tournament holds tournament related data, participant assigns a player to a tournament, and games holds tournament and non-tournament related instances of matches being played in the app, and related data such as what players played this game.
Database Visualized
My problem is with the player1 and player2 columns within the Games table.
I read a rule, that foreign keys point to a table, so it doesn't make sense having 2 different columns of the games table pointing to Users, but then would the solution be to have a foreign key in games that points to users, and through that to set player1 and player2 as varchar accordingly?
I tried having 2 players set as varchar, get the players name upon the initiation of a game session and save it that way, but it feels not correct.

But then would the solution be to have a foreign key in games that points to users, and through that to set player1 and player2 as varchar accordingly? What do you mean by "through that"? Having two different keys in the Games table pointing to different entries in the Users table seems to be fine in your case . Either that or use the same relation as in the Participants table (e.g. name it "Players") where the games and players are linked together. You might also consider replacing your keys by autoincrement IDs.

You can have to foreign keys from Games to Users - no problem.
However - Try reading up on "normal forms" for DBMS systems. It's a good idea to normalize the design. In your design for instance the number of wins and losses is redundant information, and it's easy to have inconsistent data, if the number of games with say, Player A as winner does not match PLayer A's wins column in the user table.
